# Proxy server that listen connections inside a VM

Tags: tcp, proxy, nat

I have some linux application that runs on a VM and listens TCP connections on different ports. The VM is behind a NAT. I would like to install a Proxy on that VM to listen connections and to redirect them through correctly ports.
I would like  to redirect the traffic(maybe iptables) from the VM's host to the Proxy, inside the VM.
Can you tell me what Proxy should I use and give me a short configuration example?

Comment: It sounds more like tunneling than proxying to me. What virtualizer are you using?

Comment: I am using vmware. Can you give me please a tunneling example?

Answer (score 0):

What you're talking about looks like using a server software within a guest on the host network, which would be perfectly served using Port Forwarding. See [VMWare documentation](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_net_nat_advanced.html)